# PHP While Cycle

Tags: php, html, sql, loops, while-loop

I would like to have 18 interviews and a button below each interview. But I messed up with the cycles and now I have 18 interviews with 18 buttons below each interview. It should be just one button.

I am almost sure it is a cycle problem. Can you please tell me where is my mistake?

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM interviews WHERE featured = 1";
  $featured = $db->query($sql);
?>

<div class="container">
    <table class="rwd-table">
        <tbody>
            <br><br>
            <tr>
                <?php 
        include_once("../forum/connect.php");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories2 ORDER BY category ASC";
        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $interviews = "";
if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
      $id = $row['id'];
      $category = $row['category'];

        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM interviews WHERE categories='".$id."'ORDER BY title DESC";
        $res2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($res2) > 0){

          while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
             $tid = $row2['id'];
             $title = $row2['title'];
              $interviews .= "<a href='view_interview.php?cid=".$id."&tid=".$tid."' class='cat_links'>".$category." - ".$title."</a>";      

    }
  }
}

    $counter = 0;
    while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featured)){
      $image = $product['image'];
      $title = $product['title'];
      $decs = $product['description'];
        if($counter % 3 == 0){
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
        ++$counter;


echo "<td>
<div id='element1'></div>
<div id='content1'>
            <img src=".$image." alt=".$title.">
            <h3>".$title."</h3>
            <hr>
            <h4>".$decs."</h4>

       <div id='hovers'>
      <a href='view_interview.php?cid=".$id."&tid=".$tid."' class='button' target='_blank'>
        <span class='contentbut'> Read More</span>
      </a>
    </div>";    echo $interviews; 
}
    ?>
                <br><br>

                </td>
                <?php
   }   

        ?>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: *have 18 interviews and a button below each interview. But I messed up with the cycles and now I have 18 interviews with 18 buttons below each interview* . Your statement is contradictory.

Comment: I mean there should be just one button below each interview. In other words I need to have 18 interviews and 18 buttons.

Comment: But now, I have 18 interviews and 18 buttons below each interview. That means 18*18=324 buttons.

Comment: you are having so many loops. Also, you need to format your code before posting it. To make it easy to understand your logic

Comment: I have just 3 while loops. But, I got confused and do not know how keep just one button below each interview.

Comment: @Ravi I have one page with all the interviews academy.php, from that page I can go to a specific category view_category.php and from there I can go to the interview interview.php. I would like also to be able to go from academy.php to interview.php      The code above is from academy.php

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any point query same table twice in same code.

```
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM interviews WHERE featured = 1";
  $featured = $db->query($sql);
?>

<div class="container">
    <table class="rwd-table">
        <tbody>
            <br><br>
            <tr>
                <?php 
        include_once("../forum/connect.php");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories2 ORDER BY category ASC";
        $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $interviews = "";
if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
      $id = $row['id'];
      $category = $row['category'];

        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM interviews WHERE categories='".$id."'ORDER BY title DESC";
```

Can't you `join` the `categories2` and `interviews` table and use only one loop ??

Also, below line of code is part of two loops, which is actually the reason for `18x18`.

```
<a href='view_interview.php?cid=".$id."&tid=".$tid."' class='button' target='_blank'>
```

Comment: How do you recommend to join them. You mean to join them in my phpmyAdmin or to modify that code and join them with a query. If you mean to join them with a query, can you offer a solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you have already written it `SELECT * FROM interviews WHERE categories='".$id."'ORDER BY title DESC` . You are using `category id` to query `interview` table. Then, why don't you join then in single query ?

Comment: categories is a column in interviews table and it is a foreign key of column id in categories2 table

Comment: Then, why aren't you joining them ? instead of writing two separate query ?

Comment: How do you mean to join both tables? Do you mean to modify the query something like that                 $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM interviews LEFT JOIN categories2 WHERE categories='".$id."'ORDER BY title DESC";

Comment: Yes, something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your second interview "loop" into the loop where you generate the output for the interview if the button(s) should go after each interview.

Be aware that the `features` query is not necessary bound to one result. If you have several `feature=1` records, you will have a button for each one.

The most likely is that you have 18 featured interviews.

Your loop structre is like this:

```
loop through categories[
     loop through inteviews[
          Generate output for interview
     ]
]

loop through featured interviews [
          Generate output for button
]
```

Comment: Yes, I understand. I applied the changes, but now all the 18 buttons went on the last interview?

Comment: The featured interviews are all of the 18 interviews. But, I now get all of the buttons only below the last interview.

Comment: Yoy have to mix in the buttons code into the $interview html string in the place you want the buttons to appear.

Comment: To be honest I do not know how to join the tables correctly. Can you offer me a suggestion?

Comment: Can you post your table structure and elaborate on what the program should do? Why is there a specific query to get the featured interviews for example.

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do. I want to on academy.php to see all the interviews and to choose a category. If I choose a category I go to view_category.php where I can see the interviews from a specific categories. The when I pick an interview I go to interview.php. What I am trying to do is to go from academy.php to interview.php when I click the button below the interview. Can you check my code on these files here please: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/jq64que4m2n65ii/AAC8U47dsWtotPbCFILGlvXoa?dl=0

Comment: Ok, so the first two nested whiles have the purpose of showing links to interviews by category and the last one is the list of all the featured interviews. In your original code check if you are not missing a closing td tag in the last loop.

Comment: I finnaly fixed it. First I have a loop for categories and then a loop for interviews and i echo everything in the second loop. Now, they appear only by category. For example I can see the category and all the interviews in that category and then the next category. Do you know how I can sort them by date posted and not to be sorted by category?

Comment: Check examples for sort() function in php

Comment: Thank you. I will check.